# Delete Empty Matrices in Multidimensional Array - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

I am looking for a way to delete empty matrices within a multidimensional array in MATLAB.

For example, I have a 4-D array such as:

```
N = 5;
Arr = zeros(2,2,4,N);
```

Lets assume only N = 2 and N = 4 have values (i.e the four 2x2 matrices in N = 1, 3 and 5 are zeros), how can I create another multidimensional array ArrFin(2,2,4,2) such that

```
ArrFin(2,2,4,1) = Arr(2,2,4,2); 
ArrFin(2,2,4,2) = Arr(2,2,4,4);
```

I have tried to make the question quite general so that others can benefit from it as well but if I am not making much sense let me know.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Figured out quite a neat way to do it:

```
ArrFin = Arr(:,:,:,any(any(any(Arr,3))));
```

This picks out the non zero matrices and saves them into ArrFin.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
%%// Create data
Arr= rand(2,2,4,5);
Arr(:,:,:,[1 3 5]) = 0;

%%// Get new reduced matrix and check for its size
ArrFin = Arr(:,:,:,find(sum(reshape(sum(Arr,3),size(Arr,3),size(Arr,4)),1)));
size_check  = size(ArrFin)
```

**Output**

```
size_check =

     2     2     4     2
```